# Python Text Adventure Game, Changing Locations

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm working on a text-based game in Python for a class and I'm stuck on a concept. I'm trying to setup the code so that each room has its own "def" statement. The problem is, my "location" value is not being changed to trigger the other rooms, so I'm stuck in Great Hall when I test this out. I've tried multiple solutions to try to fix this, and I'm not getting anywhere.

```
#A dictionary for the simplified dragon text game
#The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }


instructions = 'Welcome to The Dragon Text Game. You must collect items throughout the castle in preparation to defeat the dragon.\n\n To move around the castle, a prompt will appear that shows the directions you can go. \n\n move by using the "move" command along with the direction ex: "move East".\n grab items by using the "grab" command, ex. "grab sword".'

print(instructions)
while True:
    def GreatHall():
        move = ['move south']
        move_input = ''
        while move_input not in move:
            print('The only option is South. Where would you like to move?')
            move_input = input().lower()  #added .lower() function to make sure the text is ALWAYS interpreted as lower case to avoid unnecessary bugs
            if move_input == 'move south':
                print('You move south from the Great Hall to the Bedroom.\nThe Bedroom is a large, luxurious space with a high ceiling, chandelier, and a comfortable looking King bed.\n If you were not fighting a dragon, you would like a nap.')
                location = 'Bedroom'
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid option! Try again.')

    def Bedroom():
        move = ['move north', 'move east']
        move_input = ''
        while move_input not in move:
            print('You see the door you just came form to the north, an an ominous-looking stone archway on the East corner of the room leading underground. \nThe entrance is cold and dark.')
            move_input = input().lower()
            if move_input == 'move north':
                print('You return to the Great Hall.')
                location == 'Great Hall'
            elif move_input == 'move east':
                print('You make your way down the dark path and discover a cellar.')
                location == 'Cellar'
            else:
                print('Invalid option! Try again.')

    def Cellar():
        move = ['move west']
        move_input = ''
        while move_input not in move:
            print('The cellar is dark, lit by a single sconce on the wall. The walls are seeping with moisture and a distinct stale smell fills the room.\nThere are no other doorways, besides the one leading back to the Bedroom.')
            move_input = input().lower()
            if move_input == 'move west':
                print('You move back up the Bedroom.')
                location == 'Bedroom'
            else:
                print('Invalid option! Try again.')

    location = 'Great Hall'
    print('You start in the great hall\n')
    if location == 'Great Hall':
        GreatHall()
    if location == 'Bedroom':
        Bedroom()
    if location == 'Cellar':
        Cellar()
```

The "expected" behavior of the location def functions is to change the location the player is in, so that the function relating to that prints.

I've tried using "continue" or "break" functions, changed the entire loop structure, and asked my professor. I was given code, by my professor, that approaches this issue by giving me code that was done in a completely different way. Problem is, I wanted to fix my OWN code so I can learn.

Comment: It's weird to `def` the same functions again and again in a loop. A common arrangement is to create objects which correspond to the different location and separate the data into the objects and the logic into code which operates on these objects without knowing or caring which one of them the player is in etc.

Comment: I think the main problem is that your loop assigns `location = 'Great Hall'`, therefore the location always gets reset each time through the loop.  That assignment belongs _outside_ of the loop.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with how this code is structured.

> wanted to fix my OWN code so I can learn.

That is commendable.

Keep the mantra of
[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
in mind as you critique the various refactorings of your
code. Look for opportunities to extract common
data patterns into a suitable datastructure (perhaps a `dict`)
and to extract common logic into a helper function.

Also keep the
[Single-responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) principle
in mind.  Write a one-sentence """docstring""" for each function.
Ask yourself: is the great hall function doing more than one thing?
How could I break out One Thing into a helper function?

---

```
print(instructions)
while True:
    def GreatHall():
```

Those first two instructions belong in a function:

```
def main():
    print(instructions)
    while True:
        ...
```

Nested `def`'s is probably something you should avoid at
this point in your journey of learning about python.
Repeatedly asking the interpreter to define a new
function object, every time through the loop, is
very odd and in this case accomplishes nothing useful for you.

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you name it `great_hall` instead.

---

```
            if ...
                location = 'Bedroom'
```

This is a problem.

You just created a local variable named `location`.
It will go out-of-scope when the function exits.
That is, the updated value is lost.

You might assign the value to a persistent location which
is in-scope, such as `self.location` if a class were involved.
Definitely don't get sucked into the `global` trap.
Probably better that you `return location`.

---

At some point you're going to want a central verb parser,
since in every room we can consult `i` "inventory",
and can probably `l` "look".

A typical organization would be to represent the castle
as a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph),
perhaps with a `dict`, and have a `while True:` loop
cycle over that, changing the current location node as needed.
You will get there at some point.

At the moment, cleaning up those broken room functions is
your most pressing task.
You are lost in a maze of functions, all alike.
Suddenly a rogue draft of wind extinguishes your lamp...